# Are Angular Services better than Typescript Singleton Approach?

Tags: angular, typescript

Just what is says on the box really. Considering we have Singleton patterns available in TS, why would you use Angular Singleton ? Are there any benefits in using the Angular injection?

Comment: Testability, configurability, hierarchical injectors...

Comment: @JBNizet that is not really an answer. What makes it more testable? What configuration would you miss out on?

Comment: Indeed. That's why I posted it as a comment. The problems caused by the singleton anti-pattern and the advantages of DI (whatever the language or framework is) are well documented. Testability: you can pass a mock dependency when testing a component or service. You can't do that with the singleton anti-pattern. Configurability: a library can use a service without caring what its implementation is: you can provide your own implementation to customize the library.

Answer (score 2):

Angular is build up on Dependency-Injection if you would have something like statefull services which would be needed if you want to have a singleton the whole concept of `treeshaking` would be violated and you would use one of the main benefits of angular.

So **always use dependency injection**.

For storing singleton data in angular `reactive statemangagment` is the way to go:
https://ngrx.io/